# What is category of relative time and absolute time

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I have an App that shows a timeline. events in this timeline can be relative to each other or absolute from certain starting point.

I want to give this categorizing a name.

If i were to have an option where you could choose between relative and absolute timing, what should be the name of this option?

I came up with "Timing policy", but it feels weird.

Is there better word (not a sentence, prefably single word) to best describe this category?

---

Eg.

```
Timing policy = Relative
```

This means events in this timeline are relative to each other.

---

Maybe im over thinking. What about "Is Relative"? So if this property is false that means absolute.

Comment: *Timing preference* is an improvement on timing policy, but I don't think you'll get a single word that gives enough context if the options are just Relative and Absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that people would understand your use of [chronology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chronology) as a label for the type of measurement (relative or absolute). From MW:

> **[chronology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chronology)**
>
> 1. the science that deals with measuring time by regular divisions and that assigns to events their proper dates

So you can give the option as *Chronology: Relative or Absolute.*

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. thanks a lot!